# can't understand store.Certificates.Find

Tags: c#

```
var store = new X509Store(StoreName.My);

store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);

foreach (var mCert in store.Certificates)
{
   Response.Write(store.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindBySubjectName, mCert.SubjectName.Name, false).Count + "<br>"); 
}
```

Why I have count - 0 in response?